# Change tiered list item color without disabling javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

For a resume project, I made a tiered list to display various items. I found some JavaScript code that allows me to click on the top item of the list and it expands and collapses the list. To make it more easily seen, I tried to create a hover property so that it would change colors, but the only way to do this that I could find is to make a  around the text that I wanted to change, rather than using the  because it would change the color of EVERYTHING in the list. By doing it with the  tags, it disabled my JavaScript and the list items didn't expand or contract anymore. The only thing that I can do now is simply change the overall color but that isn't what I want. Please help!

The code with the links changed colors and the JavaScript works: http://pages.iu.edu/~dandfox/HELP/p1-final-h5c2.html

The code with the links hovering, but JavaScript doesn't work: http://pages.iu.edu/~dandfox/HELP/p1-final-h5c3.html

I wish to make the hovering links work WITH the JavaScript. Thank you!